# Remove cardinal direction letters

Tags: qgis

I want to remove the direction for latitude (N) and Longitude (W) and keep (°) like 52° and -130° in the map. I tried to find in the draw coordinates and format but I haven't found a way yet. I think I have to write a program in custom but I don't know it.

Edit:
Here the example of the map containing latitude and longitude values with respectively N and W. I just want to remove these two letters.

[image]

Comment: In Printcomposer grid? Please clarify and describe your question as precisely as possible.

Comment: Hi, please be more specific. Posting some screenshots will also help to get your message across.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom coordinates format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328837/custom-coordinates-format)

Answer (score 9):

Your grid coordinates format is set to "Decimal with suffix."

[image]

**Change the grid coordinate format to "Decimal."**

[image]

If you don't like any of the eight pre-formatted options, choose the "custom" setting and write an expression to achieve your desired format.

For example, to display decimal degrees with the degree symbol, use this expression:

```
 @grid_number  ||  '°'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much....It works...Sincerely

Comment: @user145527 Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your question.

Comment: @user145527 https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers